# Replace column in Pandas dataframe with the mean of that column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 3], [4, 6]], columns=['A', 'B'])

   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  3
2  4  6
```

I want to return a dataframe **of the same size** containing the mean of each column:

```
   A      B
0  2  3.666
1  2  3.666
2  2  3.666
```

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: I'm curious, what is this for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recreate the DataFrame. Send the mean Series to a dict, then the index defines the number of rows.

```
pd.DataFrame(df.mean().to_dict(), index=df.index)

#     A         B
#0  2.0  3.666667
#1  2.0  3.666667
#2  2.0  3.666667
```

---

Same concept,  but creating the full array first saves a decent amount of time.

```
pd.DataFrame(np.broadcast_to(df.mean(), df.shape), 
             index=df.index, 
             columns=df.columns)
```

---

Here are some timings. Of course this will depend slightly on the number of columns but you can see there are pretty large differences when you provide the entire array to begin with

```
import perfplot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda N: pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,100, (N, 5)),
                                 columns=[str(x) for x in range(5)]), 
    kernels=[
        lambda df: pd.DataFrame(np.broadcast_to(df.mean(), df.shape), index=df.index, columns=df.columns),
        lambda df: df.assign(**df.mean()),
        lambda df: pd.DataFrame(df.mean().to_dict(), index=df.index)
    ],
    labels=['numpy broadcast', 'assign', 'dict'],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(1, 22)],
    equality_check=np.allclose,
    xlabel="Len(df)"
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's one with [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df.assign(**df.mean())

    A         B
0  2.0  3.666667
1  2.0  3.666667
2  2.0  3.666667
```

---

**Details**

The mean is easily obtained with `DataFrame.mean`:

```
df.mean()

tenor_yrs    14.292857
rates         2.622000
dtype: float64
```

From the above `Series`, we can use *dictionary unpacking* to replace the existing columns with the resulting values. Note that we can unpack the `Series` into a dictionary using `**`:

```
{**df.mean()}
# {'tenor_yrs': 14.292857142857143, 'rates': 2.622}
```

Given that the way `assign` adds new columns is as `df.assign(a_given_column=a_value, another_column=some_other_value)`, the unpacking makes the dictionary keys be the function's arguments. And since the original dataframe's index is respected, `df.assign(**df.mean())` will replace the dataframe`s values with the means.

Comment: Added some details @merit_2

Comment: Annoyingly `assign` will have issues if the column names are not strings.

Comment: Yes that's a fair point. Not much to do about that if using `assign` I'm afraid @ALollz

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you!  I did not  understand what  ** did.

Answer (score 2):

You can only provide one single line at DataFrame creation time:

```
pd.DataFrame(data = [df.mean()], index = df.index)
```

It gives:

```
     A         B
0  2.0  3.666667
1  2.0  3.666667
2  2.0  3.666667
```